# wget reconnects every 2:30 exactly

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying to wget a 42Gb file. Every 2:30, pretty much to the second, the connection closes and wget then reconnects.

Fortunately I was able to use -c to continue the transfer and --tries=100 to pick up where it left off after the default 20 tries.

Is this timing out normal behaviour for wget? I can't see anything in the man page.

Comment: Why do you even think it has something to do with wget instead of the server? (Or your ISP)

Comment: That's why I am asking the question :P